# Is R portable when you do not to add registry keys during installation?

Tags: installation, windows-registry, r

I'm not familiar with R, and its packaging system, so forgive me if this question seems uninformed.

Judging from the help section in the R documentation it would *seem* that R is portable ([R Help 2.6](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Can-I-run-R-from-a-CD-or-USB-drive_003f)), but it does seem to imply a caveat that it's specifically a "basic installation" which is relocatable.

Can I move R (when having not added registry keys) around in a portable way?

Answer (score 0):

The help indeeds indicates that you can simply copy. I have not tried it myself. If not you should be able to use https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable.

See here for how to get also RStudio: https://rpubs.com/jsmccid/rportable

You might get into trouble if you need rJava that needs java. You can perhaps also use a portable version of Java: https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jdkportable64. More discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe